VSCode Remote-SSH can not disable tcp port forward?
The sshd_config on my server is:
AllowTcpForwarding no
AllowAgentForwarding no

And because it's a public server of my company, I can't change any settings.
So I disabled my own settings like:

In settings.json:
"remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": false,
    "remote.SSH.enableAgentForwarding": false,
    "remote.SSH.defaultForwardedPorts": [
    
    ],
    "remote.SSH.enableX11Forwarding": false,
    "remote.autoForwardPorts": false,
    "remote.forwardOnOpen": false,

But my question is, when I try to connect to the server by vscode remote-ssh, I still got the error:

I really don't understand why the port forwarding is not disabled.
Hope someone could help me solve this problem !!!

My expectation also was that disabling these settings would disable port forwarding. But according to this issue that's not the case. The forwarding is needed for setting up a port for the communication between local and remote.
There does not seem to be a plan to change this. You can use "Remote - Tunnels" as a workaround (recommended in the last comment).
